# How can CSS get the width of a window in px?

Tags: css, css-calc

I'm currently trying to write code that centers a website for which the content is exactly 895 pixels wide, and I want it to be centered. So, I'm trying to write the following in CSS:

```
body {
...
     padding-left: calc(([window width] - 895) / 2);
}
```

Is there a command which does that? is there a better way of doing this?

I have tried the following variable names:
view-width
vw
screen
screen.width
screen-width

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#relative_length_units_based_on_viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#relative_length_units_based_on_viewport)

Comment: if the container is 895, why not just margin auto it rather than adding some convoluted calc

Comment: padding-left: calc(100vw - 895px / 2); did not work, unfortunately; It messed up the actual content of the page; I'm using https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_website_layout_blog as a base

Comment: @Pete Thank you! This ended up working as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

While I did not find how to make that specific bit of code work, I found another method of centering my website; I did so with:

```
body {

. . . 

margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For window width you can use **100vw**, which actually means "100% of viewport width". You can mix that with px units inside a `calc` formula.

So the padding setting in your question would be written as

```
padding-left: calc((100vw - 895px) / 2);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this, but because of the template I used (https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_website_layout_blog), that squished everything but the header.